# Why does Expo Image Picker reset my selections when opened?

Tags: typescript, react-native, image, video, expo

Expo Image Picker does not save preselected images when re-opened. I want my preselected images that are saved in my 'useState' to show as selected images in the Image Picker (with blue checkmarks or blue numbers in the corner of each photo like Instagram/Tinder).

I can select and render my images fine. But it's just when I open the Image Picker again after I've already selected it.

ChatGPT says to use a 'selected' property to pass in an array of Images but it looks that's been deprecated? Looked through almost the entire Expo Image Picker docs but it's not helping much. Images are saved to a useState with an array type.

How can I pass in an array of imageUris or assets so that they show up as selected when users open the Image Picker again?

```
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Stack } from "tamagui";

import { Button, Text } from "../../../../components";

interface ImagePickerFormProps {
  page: number;
  setPage: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
  control: any;
}

export default function ImagePickerForm(props: ImagePickerFormProps) {
  const [pickedImages, setPickedImages] = useState<
    ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset[]
  >([]);
  const [status, requestPermission] = ImagePicker.useMediaLibraryPermissions();

  // function pick images and return assets
  // call this inside button press on click ()=> pickImage()

  const pickImages = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    if (status?.granted === false) {
      requestPermission();
    }

    //
    // THIS IS WHERE THE EXPO IMAGE PICKER IS LAUNCHED
    //
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      aspect: [16, 9],
      quality: 1,
      allowsMultipleSelection: true,
      orderedSelection: true,
      selectionLimit: 10,
      videoMaxDuration: 60,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      console.log(result.assets);
      setPickedImages(result.assets);
      return result.assets;
    }
  };

  const renderImage = (image: ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset) => (
    <Stack key={image.uri}>
      <Image source={{ uri: image.uri }} style={{ width: 180, height: 180 }} />
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ position: "absolute", top: 0, right: 0, padding: 8 }}
        onPress={() => deleteImage(image)}
      >
        <FontAwesome5 name="times-circle" size={24} color="red" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Stack>
  );

  const renderImages = () => (
    <Stack
      flexDirection="row"
      flexWrap="wrap"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      marginHorizontal={10}
      rowGap={20}
    >
      {/* append files properly */}
      {pickedImages.map(renderImage)}
    </Stack>
  );

  const deleteImage = (imageToDelete: ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset) => {
    const updatedImages = pickedImages.filter(
      (image) => image.uri !== imageToDelete.uri
    );
    setPickedImages(updatedImages);
  };

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Controller
        control={props.control}
        name="pickedImages"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <Stack>
            <Text>Images</Text>
            <Stack>
              <Button
                onPress={async () => {
                  const selectedImages = await pickImages();
                  onChange(selectedImages);
                }}
                marginVertical="$4"
              >
                <Text>Select from Camera Roll</Text>
              </Button>
              {renderImages()}
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm also wondering this as well. If you find anything, please reach out :)

Comment: @LiamWelsh i came across something that said the Expo Image Picker doesn't have this feature out of the box. I'm assuming those companies made a custom native component